# web3py error while interacting with smart contract 'message': 'execution error: revert', 'code': -32000

Tags: solidity, web3.py, ganache

When I try to interact with the contract with web3.py, I am using ganache, I get the completely useless error message:

> ValueError: {'message': 'execution error: revert', 'code': -32000, ...
>   , 'name': 'Error'}

It works correctly when using remix. This is my python code:

```
w3.eth.defaultAccount = w3.eth.accounts[0]
exams_contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
exams = w3.eth.contract(
    address=tx_receipt.contractAddress,
    abi=abi
)
tx_hash3 = exams.functions.studentAddExam(w3.eth.accounts[1]).transact()
```

And my solidity code:

```
function studentAddExam(address studentAddress) public returns (string memory returnString){
    // Receives a student's address and adds it to the people that passed that exam
    // Only the creator of the exam can do this
    string memory professorsExamHash = professorsExam[msg.sender];  // The hash of the exam owned by msg.sender
    Exam storage examObj = examHash[professorsExamHash];
    examObj.examSuccess[studentAddress] = true;
    return professorsExamHash;
}
```

I can interact with the contract using other functions.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps someone. The error was in the ABI or in the Bytecode. I replaced it and it worked.